# Expression of type serializable doesn't conform to type Option String scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am getting following compile time error here:

```
def fun1(item: TextMapWritable, field:String, language: String): Option[String] = {
    fun2(item, field, language)
      .getOrElse(fun3(item, field))
  }
```

fun2 and fun3 are returning an Option[String], but when I am trying to use them inside fun1, I am getting this error :

> Expression of type serializable doesn't conform to type Option String
>   scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `orElse`

```
def fun1(item: TextMapWritable, field:String, language: String): 
Option[String]= {
fun2(item, field, language)
  .OrElse(fun3(item, field))
}
```

because `getOrElse` returns the option's value if the option is nonempty, otherwise return the result of evaluating default. 
Please refer this [getOrElse doc.](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#getOrElse[B%3E:A](default:=%3EB):B)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want

```
def fun1(item: TextMapWritable, field:String, language: String): Option[String] =
  fun2(item, field, language) orElse fun3(item, field)
```

The problem with the original code is that `getOrElse` is taking the `String` out of the `Option` but the result is `Option[String]` so you want to keep the string in the `Option`